# rbenv: bundle: command not found on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano

I am trying to deploy rails application but its stuck with the error

```
DEBUG[1a70ba92] Command: cd /home/deploy/myapp/releases/20140615090226 && ( PATH=$HOME/.rbenv   /shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --binstubs /home/deploy/myapp/shared/bin --path /home/deploy/myapp/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
DEBUG[1a70ba92]     rbenv: bundle: command not found
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xx: bundle exit status: 127
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: rbenv: bundle: command not found
```

deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.1.0'

set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:username/myapp.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app
 set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/myapp'

# Default value for :scm is :git
# set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"

# Default value for :format is :pretty
# set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
# set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
 set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
 set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }
set :default_env, { path: "$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" }
# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
       execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  end

    desc "Symlink shared config files"
    task :symlink_config_files do
        run "#{ try_sudo } ln -s #{ deploy_to }/shared/config/database.yml #{ current_path }/config/database.yml"
    end

end
```

capfile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_ruby, "2.1.2"
```

Production.rb

```
set :stage, :production
role :app, %w{deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx}
role :web, %w{deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx}
role :db,  %w{deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx}
set :password, ask('Server password', nil)
server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx', user: 'deploy', password: fetch(:password), roles: %w{web app}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        server_name mydomain.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /home/deploy/myapp/current/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}


which ruby
/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby

ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95
```

It is using right ruby version.But i guess trying to install gems in another folder.How can I fix it?

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried installing the gem "bundler" first on your server? This gem is required to run the bundle command. SSH to your server and run the following command:

```
gem install bundler
```

Hope that helps

Comment: `deploy@movieseat:/$ sudo gem install bundler
[sudo] password for deploy: 
Successfully installed bundler-1.7.4
1 gem installed`

But I'm still getting the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using RVM or rbenv?

Comment: I'm using rbenv. maybe you can take a look at my question here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689521/error-deploying-rails-app

Comment: First, you need to make sure that you are using correct Ruby version when running "gem install bunder". And I don't know why you use "sudo"?

Comment: There was something wrong in my setup. After removing the droplet and doing the guide again I got it fixed. It was indeed something with the `gem install bundler`. Did it in the wrong order I guess.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have bundler installed (bundler -v) give this a try (it worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS):

```
1. gem uninstall bundler
2. gem update
3. gem install bundler
4. redeploy
```

Comment: this worked for me. I didnt want to start from square 1:).

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.Change user below with your user name.

sudo pico /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh

```
#File
export RBENV_ROOT=/home/user/.rbenv
export PATH=$RBENV_ROOT/shims:$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
#End File
```

Answer (score 2):

Update:
I find the reason: my .gemrc include "gem: --user-install", so the bundle not install in rbenv, and then rbenv can't find the bundle binary in 2.1.2 path
remove the --user-install config, and reinstall bundle resovle the problem.

===================================
I found that the RBENV_VERSION env cause bundle failed, but don't known why.
I remove the RBENV_VERSION and exec the cmd on the server, it succeed.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your .bashrc or .bash_profile, you will see something like that:

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Or:

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

This prevents everything after this line to be executed if the shell is not interactive.

Capistrano does not open an interactive shell.

If you are using rbenv **for example**, it adds lines at the end of your .bashrc.
These lines are not executed, so your ruby environment is not loaded.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
```

Just move the rbenv lines at the start of your .bashrc, before the return explained above.